# Выводим массив в отсортированном по возрастанию веса порядке в Java. Где ошибка?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие у меня ошибки в сортировке людей в массиве по возрастанию их веса?

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Human[] humans = new Human[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {
            humans[i] = new Human();
            humans[i].setName("User" + i);
            humans[i].setWeight(100-i);
        }

    public static void selectionSort(Human[] humans){
        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {
            int min = humans[i].getWeight();
            int minIndex = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < humans.length; j++) {
                if (humans[j].getWeight() < min) {
                    min = humans[j].getWeight();
                    minIndex = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = humans[i].getWeight();
            humans[i].getWeight() = humans[minIndex];
            humans[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(humans[i].getName() + "  " + humans[i].getWeight() + "  ");

        }
}
```

}

Comment: Посмотрите пример пузырьковой сортировки и сравните с вашим кодом.

Comment: Можно подробности ошибки?

Comment: @ArchDemon Как передать?

Comment: Вы пробовали хотя бы попытаться скомпилировать ваш код?  Компилятор обязан был выдать вам массу разных ошибок, начиная от объявления метода `selectionSort` **внутри** метода `main`, попытки присвоить `int` значению, возвращаемому из метода `getWeight` объекта `Human` и в следующей строчке наоборот - ссылке на объект `Human`  присвоить целое значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human[] humans = new Human[9];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {
            //перепишите заполнение веса
            //humans[i] = new Human("User" + i, 100 - i);
            humans[i] = new Human("User" + i, (int)(Math.random() * 100));
        }
        selectionSort(humans);
        for (Human human : humans) {
            System.out.println(human.getName() + "  " + human.getWeight() + "  ");
        }
    }
    public static void selectionSort(Human[] humans){
        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length - 1; i++) {
            int minIndex = i;
            for (int j = i; j < humans.length; j++) {
                if (humans[j].getWeight() < humans[minIndex].getWeight()) {
                    minIndex = j;
                }
            }
            //и сортировку
            //int temp = humans[i].getWeight();
            //humans[i].setWeight(humans[minIndex].getWeight());
            //humans[minIndex].setWeight(temp);
            Human temp = humans[i];
            humans[i] = humans[minIndex];
            humans[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

}

class Human {
    private String name;
    private int weight;
    Human(String name, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если сортировать массив, заполнение которого написали вы, то достаточно просто вывести его с конца. Выше исправил на рабочий вариант

Comment: Ой, пардон, не посмотрел, кто ответил)

Comment: @btwlav вариант рабочий, вот сортирует только вес , а надо , чтоб людей по весу.

Comment: я смотрю, тут не столько советуют, сколько минусуют

Comment: @and73, некорректная сортировка была давно закомментирована, существующий код сортирует людей по весу вполне корректно.

Comment: @Alex Rudenko  Точно! Всё работает! Спасибо вам большое!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий код

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human[] humans = new Human[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {

            humans[i] = new Human("User" + i, (int)(Math.random() * 100));
        }
        selectionSort(humans);
        for (Human human : humans) {
            System.out.println(human.getName() + "  " + human.getWeight() + "  ");
        }
    }
    public static void selectionSort(Human[] humans){
        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length - 1; i++) {
            int minIndex = i;
            for (int j = i; j < humans.length; j++) {
                if (humans[j].getWeight() < humans[minIndex].getWeight()) {
                    minIndex = j;
                }
            }
            Human temp = humans[i];
            humans[i] = humans[minIndex];
            humans[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}



public class Test {
}
class Human {
    private String name;
    private int weight;
    Human(String name, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Спасибо большое всем участникам и отдельно @btwlav!